# .NET 8 Web-API Returns empty List

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I use a `IActionResult` to get a `List<Object>`.
If I have a list, the result is ok. If I use a `List<User>`, the elements of the result are empty.

If I use a generic List, it works:

```
public IActionResult GetData()
{
  var erg1 = _database.table.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.firstname, x.lastname });
  return Ok(erg1);
}
```

I get a List with all Elements:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "732fdbd7-c878-45e8-8c43-5f795a697f6d",
    "firstname": "Uwe",
    "lastname": "Gabbert"
  },
  {
    "id": "5288f9ea-25a2-4ffc-a711-7c0b2cf49c38",
    "firstname": "User",
    "lastname": "Test"
  }
]
```

But, If I use a separate class for the elements, I get a empty List:

```
public IActionResult GetData()
{
    var erg2 = _database.table.Select(x => new User( x.Id, x.firstname, x.lastname ));
    return Ok(erg2);
}
```

In erg2 are 2 Items of User. But the return of `getData` is:

```json
[
  {},
  {}
]
```

Here the User-class:

```
public class User
{
    public string Id = "";
    public string Firstname = "";
    public string Lastname = "";

    public User(string id, string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        Id = id;
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user class only contains fields, no properties. By default, only properties get serialized.

In the working case, you are instantiating *anonymous types*, not Users. Anonymous types *by definition* have properties, they don't support fields or methods.

To solve your problem, you can turn your fields into properties.

```
public class User
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Firstname { get; set; }
  public string Lastname { get; set; }

  public User(string id, string firstname, string lastname)
  {
    Id = id;
    Firstname = firstname;
    Lastname = lastname;
  }
}
```

As a sidenote, initializing either fields or properties to "" is spurious if you have a constructor that always assigns these values.

If you really don't want to use properties, you can configure the webapi json serializer to include fields. *Note that this pretty non-standard and might confuse other people working with your code*.

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o =>
{
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
});
```